# 2001 katana 600f

Tags: starting, carburetor, cranks-wont-run, fast-idle, katana

I bought this bike not running. Did simple stuff like plugs, fresh fuel, air filter, and so on. My problem ous the bike starts great and runs strong for about 5 to 10 min or approximately a mile or 2 then dies. Have to wait 3 to 5 min then it restarts. Keep repeating the cycle no matter if bike is cold or not. I checked spark its good, checked fuel add its good. Im at a total loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you have a fueling problem. I'm not sure if your Katana has gravity feed for your fuel (would be if it has a carburetor) or has a fuel pump (if it's fuel injected). If it has a fuel pump, it could be your fuel pump is going out. If it runs for a bit, then overheats and shuts down, would behave exactly as you describe. You'd have to put a fuel pressure gauge on it to tell if it's doing what it's doing, though. Or some way to know if the fuel pump is continuing to run.

Comment: When it dies take the fuel cap off, if you hear a sucking noise when you do then the tank isn't venting properly and you're getting vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

Had problem like this before, it turned out to be the coil, once it got hot it separated an internal contact.

I fitted a new coil and it was fine. If you can get a known good spare that would be a good test.